# Adding jquery into a composite control

Tags: jquery, asp.net, composite-controls

I am creating a composite control that has a textbox and uses a jquery plugin to add a watermark. Lets say I have a basic function that looks like this

```
$(function () {$('#MyTextBoxID').watermark('Enter your username');});
```

Can anyone suggest what I need to do to insert the above?

TIA!

Answer (score 0):

You can register a startup script and using it you can do following:

```
 Dim cs As ClientScriptManager = Page.ClientScript
 If (Not cs.IsStartupScriptRegistered(cstype, csname1)) Then
      Dim cstext1 As String = "$(function () {$('#" & Me.ClientID & "').watermark('Enter your username');});"
      cs.RegisterStartupScript(cstype, csname1, cstext1, True)

End If
```